# Divergence of current density with explicit and implicit dependence?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

This is a question in regards to Chapter 10 of Griffiths E&M. Suppose I want to take the divergence of $\vec{J}(\vec{r} ',t_r)$. where $t_r=t-R/c$ and $R$ is the separation from the source point to the observation point. If I want to find $\nabla\cdot\vec{J}$, then since $\vec{J}$ depends implicitly on $\vec{r}$ through $t_r$ I don't need to care about the $\vec{r}'$ dependence of $\vec{J}$. Since the divergence obeys the chain rule I get:
\begin{equation}
\nabla\cdot\vec{J}=\frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t_r}\nabla(t_r)
\end{equation}
My question is how do I find $\nabla '\cdot\vec{J}$ where $\nabla '$ denotes derivatives with respect to $\vec{r}'$. Here we have both explicit dependence and implicit dependence through $t_r$. So how do i find
\begin{equation}
\nabla '\cdot \vec{J}(\vec{r}',t_r)=\,?
\end{equation}
Edit: Someone suggested just expanding using the chain rule. So if we think of $\vec{J}=(J_x,J_y,J_z)$ then:
\begin{equation}
\nabla\cdot\vec{J}=\left(\frac{\partial J_x}{\partial x'}+\frac{\partial J_x}{\partial t_r}\frac{\partial t_r}{\partial x'}\right)+\dots
\end{equation}
which means you can write it as
\begin{equation}
\nabla '\cdot\vec{J}=\left(\frac{\partial J_x}{\partial x'}+\frac{\partial J_y}{\partial y'}+\frac{\partial J_z}{\partial z'}\right)+\frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t_r}\cdot\nabla 't_r
\end{equation}
So it's basically like taking the divergence of $\vec{J}$ if it had no implicit dependence and then adding on the implicit dependence term? Would this be the proper notation?
\begin{equation}
\nabla '\cdot\vec{J}(\vec{r}',t_r)=\nabla '\cdot \vec{J}(\vec{r}')+\frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t_r}\cdot\nabla 't_r
\end{equation}

Comment: Have you tried just applying the chain rule? The multidimensional version covers exactly this situation.

Comment: Yeah, I have made som additions to my post.

Comment: The thing is the multivariable version of the chain rule works exactly on these types of questions, what trouble are you having while applying it?

Comment: I have added some stuff to my post, I guess I just want to make sure that this is indeed correct and that my final answer has the right notation, I am a bit unsure on that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\nabla' \cdot \vec{J}(\vec{r}' , t_{r})$$

Assuming $\vec{r}' = x' \hat i + y' \hat j + y' \hat k$

Let's look at a single component of the divergence, from the multivariable chain rule
[The $\vec{r}'$ is short hand for x',y',z']

$\frac{d}{dx'} J_{x}(\vec{r}' , t_{r}) = \frac{\partial J_{x}(\vec{r}' , t_{r})}{\partial x'}  + \frac{\partial J_{x}(\vec{r}' , t_{r})}{\partial t_{r}}\frac{d t_{r}}{dx'}$

Doing the same for each component and adding them gets you your desired result

$$\nabla'(t_{r}) \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t_{r}} + (\nabla' \cdot \vec{J})_{t_{r}} $$

Where the last expression is taking the divergence, assuming tr is not a function of r'

Comment: Better notation for this last part could be $$\nabla \cdot \vec{J}(\vec{k},t_{r})[\vec{r}',t_{r}] $$ Where we are taking the gradient with respect to the vector k, evaluated at r'